# Testing component created using styled component with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a few tags created using styled components lib:

component.js

```
....
const NoJobs = styled.h1`
    text-align: center;
`;
....
<div>
  <NoJobs>
    No Jobs Found!!!
  </NoJobs>
</div>
```

I want to test this component, below is my test case:

component.test.js

```
describe('<JobList />', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<JobList />);
    });

    it('should show "no data found" when there is no data', () => {
       expect(wrapper.contains(<NoJobs>No Jobs Found!!!</NoJobs>)).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

When I run above test it show: NoJobs is not defined.

Though if I change NoJobs with plan div tag in both component.js and component.test.js, it works fine. How can I test tags created using styled-components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Quick way***

You may export `NoJobs` like

```
const NoJobs = styled.h1`...
```

And that will work. Also you may use [`find()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) that may take a `displayName` string, so you can

```
const NoJobs = styled.h1`...
NoJobs.displayName = "NoJobs";
```

and then in test:

```
expect(wrapper.find('NoJobs').text()).toEqual("No Jobs Found!!!");
```

Also you can install [special babel plugin](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging) to handle that automatically.

***Systematic approach***

But to me most maintainable way is avoid sticking to dislayname/component name at all and use attribute-based selectors:

```
<div>
  <NoJobs data-testid="no-jobs-message">
    No Jobs Found!!!
  </NoJobs>
</div>
```

and later in test

```
expect(wrapper.find({"data-testid": "no-jobs-message"}).text()).toEqual("No Jobs Found!!!")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the second approach, it worked perfectly fine.Will it have any performance impact if I use same approach in large applications?

Comment: I'd not expect any performance hits. But it's worse for maintainability, and that's important for large application.

Comment: So what is the recommended way for large applications?

Comment: "systematic approach" with attribute-based lookup(not necessarily with syntethic `data-testid` but it's good first candidate). also this makes your code ready to e2e tests() that rather obligatory for large applications